# MATLAB: bnb20 (Branch and Bound Method) Optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization

I've got an error when running the following code in `matlab`. I'm trying to use bnb20.

```
    function [errmsg,Z,X,t,c,fail] = optimize_bnb_test
        P = [34336 701 227 2860 32841 463 616 39769 331 1224 1515 472583
 1021 969 9260 39380 4986 6567 3386 16926 4841 100635];
        C = 31300;        
        A = [-C 0 0; 0 -C 0; 0 0 -C;];        
        B =[-P(1); -P(2); -P(3);];
        function y = linear_objective(n)
            y = [1, 1, 1] * n;
        end    
        lb = [1; 1; 1;];
        ub = [16; 16; 16; ];

        [errmsg,Z,X,t,c,fail] = BNB20('linear_objective',lb,[],lb,ub,A,B,
[],[],[],[],[],[]);        
    end
```

I got an error message like 'fun cause error.'

I don't know why.

I'm just learning `matlab`.

[image]

Update:

```
    function [errmsg,Z,X,t,c,fail] = optimize_bnb_test
    P = [34336 701 227 2860 32841 463 616 39769 331 1224 1515 472583 1021 969 9260 39380 4986 6567 3386 16926 4841 100635];
    C = 31300;        
    A = [-C 0 0; 0 -C 0; 0 0 -C;];        
    B =[-P(1); -P(2); -P(3);];

    lb = [1; 1; 1;];
    ub = [16; 16; 16;];
    fun = @(x)x(1)+x(2)+x(3);

    [errmsg,Z,X,t,c,fail] = BNB20('fun',lb,[],lb,ub,A,B,[],[],[],[],[]);         
    end
```

Error message is changed:

[image]

I don't know what to do now..

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Comment: The exact error is .. "fun caused error."

Comment: Oh I see, `bnb20` is not a inbuilt fuction but a fileexchange...

Comment: In your update there is not anymore a function declaration of `fun`, thus the error you get is "Undefined function `fun`" (the name before was `linear_objective`). Why did you deleted it ?

Answer (score 1):

The error happens the following call:

```
eval(['z=',fun,'(x0,varargin{:});'],'errmsg=''fun caused error.''; evalreturn=1;');
```

My guess is that varargin{:} is giving an error to your function. It looks like you don't use it, it is empty. I would try either of:

1.- delete the last `,[]` from the call to `bnb20` as the 13th input argument is optional, instead of giving an empty array (`[]`), just don't give anything.

2.- When you define your function to evaluate, define it with extra input arguments but dump then (or just do not use them).

```
function y = linear_objective(n,varargin)
       y = [1, 1, 1] * n;
end
```

Comment: @wntun Take the first code you posted and copy paste the one I have here on top of your `function y = ....`.